# Makefile project won't build after no changes to makefile (near identical make, works fine)

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have compiled a makefile project under linux, just yesterday. Now the project won't compile and I can't remember making any change whatsoever to the makefile itself. It throws a `make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/TranquilMain.o', needed by 'tranquil;. Stop.` error at `make`. The only real change I've made, is when I copied the code and makefile over from another project, I changed the name of certain files (and dependencies includes) and then altered the `_DEPS` in the makefile. All files in necessary locations.

It should be noted that it compiles fine, if I remove all other files than TranquilMain.o from the _OBJ list. `enter code here`I wish I could provide more than just code, and this knowledge, but I haven't a clue what the problem is.

Appropriate Makefile: "makefile"

```
#!/usr/bin/make

CC      = gcc
CP      = g++

SRC_DIR     = #.
OBJ_DIR     = obj
INC_DIR     = ../include
LIB_DIR     = ../lib

LIBS        = -lm -lSDL -lSDLmain -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_ttf -lSDL_net -lGL -lGLU -lGLEW
CFLAGS      = -I$(INC_DIR) -L$(LIB_DIR) -std=gnu++0x


_DEPS   = DefaultConfig.h BaseApplication.h BasePlugin.h SDLImage.h SDLFont.h SDLWindow.h SDLInput.h SDLRenderer.h SDLApplication.h Math2D.h SDLTimer.h
DEPS    = $(patsubst %,$(INC_DIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

_OBJ    = TranquilMain.o BaseApplication.o BasePlugin.o SDLImage.o SDLFont.o SDLWindow.o SDLInput.o SDLRenderer.o SDLApplication.o Math2D.o SDLTimer.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(OBJ_DIR)/%,$(_OBJ))


$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CP) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

tranquil: $(OBJ)
    $(CP) -o ../bin/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ_DIR)/*.o *~ core $(INC_DIR)/*~
```

Clearly useless TranquilMain.cpp (just the first file in the dependencies)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    bool running = true;

    while( running == true )
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `INC_DIR     = ../include #-I../include/tryp` looks super suspicious. My first attempt would be to remove the `#-I../include/tryp` part.

Comment: Damn, I've actually already tried it without those "commented" bits. I'll remove them in the code so as to remove future regards >.< sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, make sure you haven't inadvertantly turned tabs into whitespace.

A rule *MUST* begin with a "tab":

```
#BAD!
tranquil: $(OBJ)
<space><space>$(CP) -o ../bin/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

#GOOD!
tranquil: $(OBJ)
<tab>$(CP) -o ../bin/$@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Answer (score 2):

When I start with the above Makefile, and the project structure

```
├── include/
└── src/
    ├── Makefile
    ├── TranquilMain.cpp
    └── obj/
```

Then I get the same `` make: *** No rule to make target `obj/TranquilMain.o', needed by `tranquil'. `` error that you report above. What causes this? Let's run make in debug mode to find out.

First add

```
.SUFFIXES:
%:: SCCS/s.%
%:: RCS/%
%:: RCS/%,v
%:: %,v
%:: s.%
```

to the top of the Makefile to cancel some default rules that will only clutter the debug output.

Then, run `make -d`:

```
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
Reading makefiles...
Reading makefile `Makefile'...
Updating makefiles....
 Considering target file `Makefile'.
  Looking for an implicit rule for `Makefile'.
  No implicit rule found for `Makefile'.
  Finished prerequisites of target file `Makefile'.
 No need to remake target `Makefile'.
Updating goal targets....
Considering target file `tranquil'.
 File `tranquil' does not exist.
  Considering target file `obj/TranquilMain.o'.
   File `obj/TranquilMain.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `obj/TranquilMain.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `TranquilMain'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `TranquilMain.cpp'.
   Trying rule prerequisite `../include/DefaultConfig.h'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `TranquilMain'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `TranquilMain.cpp'.
   Trying rule prerequisite `../include/DefaultConfig.h'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file `../include/DefaultConfig.h'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for `obj/TranquilMain.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `obj/TranquilMain.o'.
  Must remake target `obj/TranquilMain.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target `obj/TranquilMain.o', needed by `tranquil'.  Stop.
```

`make` first makes sure the `Makefile` is up to date. Then it tries to make the `tranquil` target by performing a depth-first search, building all required dependencies. `tranquil` depends on `${OBJ}`, the first element of which is `obj/TranquilMain.o`. By the `${OBJDIR}/%.o` rule, that depends on `TranquilMain.cpp` and all of `${DEPS}`. The first element of `${DEPS}` is `../include/DefaultConfig.h`, so `make` tries to build it. But it does not exist and there are no rules to build it. `make` concludes it cannot build `obj/TranquilMain.o` using this rule, because there are missing dependencies. It tries to find another rule to build it using other dependencies that do exist, but there are no such rules. So `make` stops, saying, “No [valid] rule [for which dependencies exist or can be built] to make target `obj/TranquilMain.o`.”

What's the solution? Make sure all the dependencies exist. With this Makefile, to compile anything, your project must contain, at minimum:

```
.
├── include/
│   ├── BaseApplication.h
│   ├── BasePlugin.h
│   ├── DefaultConfig.h
│   ├── Math2D.h
│   ├── SDLApplication.h
│   ├── SDLFont.h
│   ├── SDLImage.h
│   ├── SDLInput.h
│   ├── SDLRenderer.h
│   ├── SDLTimer.h
│   └── SDLWindow.h
├── lib/
└── src/
    ├── BaseApplication.cpp
    ├── BasePlugin.cpp
    ├── Makefile
    ├── Math2D.cpp
    ├── SDLApplication.cpp
    ├── SDLFont.cpp
    ├── SDLImage.cpp
    ├── SDLInput.cpp
    ├── SDLRenderer.cpp
    ├── SDLTimer.cpp
    ├── SDLWindow.cpp
    ├── TranquilMain.cpp
    └── obj/
```

And you will likely need to add library files to `lib/` to get a final executable as well.

Comment: My tree is accurate, all files are in their correct locations, which is exactly why I find it unexplainable.

Comment: Well then, what does `make -d` output?